# Jackson XML to JSON conversion: How to exclude a specific tag in XML by retaining the inner values during the conversion?

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, fasterxml

I am trying to convert the XML data to JSON using the Java Jackson library. As of now, I am able to convert the XML to JSON but I would like to remove a specific XML tag by retaining the inner values in it.

Suppose my XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
    <Employee>
        <extension>
            <FirstName>Tanmay</FirstName>
            <LastName>Patil</LastName>
            <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>
        </extension>
    </Employee>
</Company>
```

As per the requirement, I would like my JSON to be:

```
{
  "Employee": {
    "FirstName": "Tanmay",
    "LastName": "Patil",
    "ContactNo": "1234567890"
  }
}
```

I do not want to have `extension` tag in the JSON. How can I skip this tag but retaining the values within it?

Following is my code which is converting the XML to JSON using Jackson:

```
public class ApplicationMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, URISyntaxException {
        String absolutePath = Paths.get(ApplicationMain.class.getClassLoader().getResource("inputData.xml").toURI()).toFile().getAbsolutePath();
        Path fileName = Path.of(absolutePath);
        String xmlInputData = Files.readString(fileName);
        // System.out.println(xmlInputData);

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        JsonNode node = xmlMapper.readTree(xmlInputData.getBytes());
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(node);
        System.out.println(json);
    }

}
```

Comment: Underscore-java library has a static method U.xmlToJson(xml).

Answer (score 0):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) library can convert xml to json.

```
    String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n" +
            "<Company>\n" +
            "    <Employee>\n" +
            "        <extension>\n" +
            "            <FirstName>Tanmay</FirstName>\n" +
            "            <LastName>Patil</LastName>\n" +
            "            <ContactNo>1234567890</ContactNo>\n" +
            "        </extension>\n" +
            "    </Employee>\n" +
            "</Company>";
    Map<String, Object> objectMap = U.fromXmlMap(xml);
    U.set(objectMap, "Company.Employee", U.get(objectMap, "Company.Employee.extension"));
    System.out.println(U.toJson(U.<Map<String, Object>>get(objectMap, "Company")));

// {
//   "Employee": {
//     "FirstName": "Tanmay",
//     "LastName": "Patil",
//     "ContactNo": "1234567890"
//   }
// }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse. Is it possible to do using the Jackson Library?

Comment: You may convert xml to map, modify it and generate json.